# How to loop over a list incrementally

Tags: python-3.x

```
listname = ['bartian', 'lenana', 'kilimanjaro', 'uhuru', 'elgon', 'everest']
while True:    
    if listname[:-1] == everest:
print(listname[:-1]+=)
```

I need a way to loop over this list and print the items in the list. I dont know whether this is pythonic since am having trouble printing the items. I want it to print from the last to first, middle item to lst or to first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way to solve your task is by using a `for` loop on a slice of your original list.

```
for name in listname[::-1]:
    print(name)
```

This prints the names in reverse order. The `[::-1]` slice says to go from one end to the other, with a step size of -1. For this specific case, you could also use `reversed`, but if you want to do other kinds of slicing it might make sense to use a slice here too, for symmetry.

Here are slices for the other forms you wanted:

```
for name in listname[len(listname)//2:]: # iterate on a slice from middle to end
    print(name)

for name in listname[len(listname)//2::-1]: # slice from the middle back to the start
    print(name)
```

Your code also has an `if` statement in it, but you don't describe what you want for it to do. If you're only printing names that are `"everest"` there's not much point to the loop!